# Login, getting name and logout error

Tags: php

I am wondering whether this is really secure that i made. However there is one error such as logout. My name is still there after isset.

here is for login and it's successful. --> login.php

```
session_start();
    if($loginRow === 1) {

      $_SESSION['login'] = true;
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

      header ("Location: index");
      } else {
      echo "Invalid Login Information";
      }
```

And also getting the username inside. It's working well. --> index.php

```
    session_start();    

if($_SESSION['login'] = "1") {
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<a href=\"logout\"> Logout </a>";
    } else {
    echo "<a href=\"register\"> Register </a>";
    }
```

and logout --> logout.php

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['login']);
$_SESSION['login'] = 0;

header ("Location: index");
```

Why after I logged out, my name is still there? I thought it has been destroyed? And also can you check whether there is a way to make it more secure? Guide me, thanks!

*I am aware I didn't put extension because I am using htaccess. So it won't be a problem.*

Comment: After you logout, use [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Comment: first you miss == in this line "if($_SESSION['login'] = "1") {" and also unset the $_SESSION['username'] variable at logout page

Comment: @ankurbhadania it would be better if you put on the answer so I can mark your answer up

Comment: Use `session_destroy()` to delete ALL data associated with that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you missing  **==** in this line `if($_SESSION['login'] = "1") {`

```
//if($_SESSION['login'] == "1") {
```

and also unset the `$_SESSION['username']`

**logout.php** add this

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake here: 
`if($_SESSION['login'] = "1")`
It should be `if($_SESSION['login'] === TRUE)`
The single = is just setting it to 1 which will always return true

Answer (score 0):

It should be `if($_SESSION['login'] == 1)` or `if($_SESSION['login'] == true)` or `if($_SESSION['login'])`